# Reading character and integer separated by spacer in C

Tags: c, input, scanf, gets

I would like to ask if there is a way how to read (stdin) input where is letter(space)number and save the letter to char and number to int. So, basically, I need to say to the "scanf" of "get" that they should stop reading after first spacer is entered. I am looking for easier way than getting string and than reading it character by character.

Thank you so much

Ref. input:

H 1234

Ref. work:

char a='H'
int b=1234

Comment: how about `char a; int b; scanf("%c %d", &a, &b);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scanf` like:

```
char input[] = "H 1234";
char c;
int i;

sscanf(input, "%c %d", &c, &i);

// Prints out the character and the number
printf("Charcter: %c, integer: %d", c, i);

return 0;
```